# Splitting individual contour points into it's HSV channels to perform additional operations

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently playing around idea of calculating an of average HSV for points in a contour. I did some research and came across the split function which allows for a mat of an image to be broken into it's channels, However the contour datatype is a vector of points. Here is an example of code.

```
findcontours(detected_edges,contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);    
vector<vector<Point>> ContourHsvChannels(3);
split(contours,ContourHsvChannels);
```

Basically the goal is to split each point of a contour into its HSV channels so I can perform operations on them. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply draw the contours onto a blank image the same size as your original image to create a mask, and then use that to mask your image (in HSV or whatever colorspace you want). The [`mean()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) function takes in a `mask` parameter so that you only get the mean of the values highlighted by the mask.

If you also want the standard deviation you can use the [`meanStdDev()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#meanstddev) function, it also accepts a `mask`.

Here's an example in Python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image, ensure binary
img = cv2.imread('fg.png', 0)
img[img>0] = 255

# find contours in the image
contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]

# create an array of blank images to draw contours on
n_contours = len(contours)
contour_imgs = [np.zeros_like(img) for i in range(n_contours)]

# draw each contour on a new image
for i in range(n_contours):
    cv2.drawContours(contour_imgs[i], contours, i, 255)

# color image of where the HSV values are coming from
color_img = cv2.imread('image.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(color_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# find the means and standard deviations of the HSV values for each contour
means = []
stddevs = []
for cnt_img in contour_imgs:
    mean, stddev = cv2.meanStdDev(hsv, mask=cnt_img)
    means.append(mean)
    stddevs.append(stddev)

print('First mean:')
print(means[0])
print('First stddev:')
print(stddevs[0])
```

> First mean:
>   [[ 146.3908046 ]
>    [  51.2183908 ]
>    [ 202.95402299]]
>
> First stddev:
>   [[  7.92835204]
>    [ 11.78682811]
>    [  9.61549043]]

There's three values; one for each channel.

---

The other option is to just look up all the values; a contour is an array of points, so you can index the image with those points for each contour in your contour array and store them in individual arrays, and then find the `meanStdDev()` or `mean()` over those (and not bother with the mask). For e.g. (again in Python, sorry about that):

```
# color image of where the HSV values are coming from
color_img = cv2.imread('image.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(color_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# read image, ensure binary
img = cv2.imread('fg.png', 0)
img[img>0] = 255

# find contours in the image
contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]

means = []
stddevs = []
for contour in contours:
    contour_colors = []
    n_points = len(contour)
    for point in contour:
        x, y = point[0]
        contour_colors.append(hsv[y, x])
    contour_colors = np.array(contour_colors).reshape(1, n_points, 3)
    mean, stddev = cv2.meanStdDev(contour_colors)
    means.append(mean)
    stddevs.append(stddev)

print('First mean:')
print(means[0])
print('First stddev:')
print(stddevs[0])
```

> First mean:
>   [[ 146.3908046 ]
>    [  51.2183908 ]
>    [ 202.95402299]]
>
> First stddev:
>   [[  7.92835204]
>    [ 11.78682811]
>    [  9.61549043]]

So this gives the same values. In Python I just simply created blank lists for the means and standard deviations and appended to them. In C++ you can create a `std::vector<cv::Vec3b>` (assuming `uint8` image, otherwise `Vec3f` or whatever is appropriate) for each. Then inside the loop I create another blank list to hold the colors for each contour; again this would be a `std::vector<cv::Vec3b>`, and then run the `meanStdDev()` on *that* vector in each loop, and append the value to the means and standard deviations vectors. You don't have to append, you can easily grab the number of contours and the number of points in each contour and preallocate for speed, and then just index into those vectors instead of appending.

In Python there's virtually no speed difference between either method. Of course there's better memory efficiency in the second example; instead of storing a whole blank `Mat` we just store a few of the values. However the backend OpenCV methods work really quickly for masking operations, so you'll have to test the speed difference yourself in C++ and see which way is better. As the number of contours increases I imagine the benefits of the second method increases. If you do time both approaches, please let us know your results!

Comment: Was about to post code of this but your answer is clear enough :)

Comment: I also want to calculate the Standard deviation within the threshold I am masking. So I will need the value of the individual pixels for H S and V values respectively.

Comment: @Zindarod well thanks because I'm writing an example script for this right now :)

Comment: @JulienPopa-Liesz you can grab the mean from `mean()` or both the mean and standard deviation with `meanStdDev()`, both accept a mask parameter.

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds I see, so if I want to compare the standard deviation of 2 different contours I will have to copy each contour separately into its own mat? and the calculate the SD? wouldn't that be expensive?

Comment: @JulienPopa-Liesz No, that's why he said to provide a mask. A mask is a single channel CV_8U image where you draw your contours.

Comment: Yes, you would have to do that. It is a little expensive but I mean, the program should still run very quickly; 8U Mats really don't take up *that* much memory for a reasonable sized image. @Zindarod The OP wants a mean and standard deviation of *each* contour, not all of them---so yes, he'd have to create `n` mask `Mat`s where `n` is the number of contours.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds that was my worst fear haha, I was curious if for looping through each contours points in one for loop would be less expensive to do. Mind you I am doing this calculation in real time. I will test your implementation and see what performance I obtain.

Comment: @JulienPopa-Liesz Your other option of course is to go through all the contour points in each contour (making sure to use `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` to store *every* contour point), and using each point to lookup the values and store each one of those. You'd have a double for loop (one for every contour (lets say `n` contours), one for every point inside a contour (say `m` points)), lookup the values in the HSV image at each point in the contour then create an `m` length `Vec3b` for each contour to store all the values in, and then you can calculate the `meanStddev()` from those `n` `Vec3b`s.

Comment: @JulienPopa-Liesz so you'd have a `vector` of `Vec3b` pixels; you'll have `n` contour `Vec3b`s containing the pixel values, and you want the `meanStdDev` of each `Vec3b`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks a lot man, you really saved a lot of my time narrowing down some documentation I would have had to sift through. I will test out your algorithm and alternate options.

Comment: @JulienPopa-Liesz No problem. I added the second method to the answer. I'll edit in a sec with the differences between C++ and Python for the second method (I think the first method is fairly clear). Edit: added C++ specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution written in c++

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


// Mat Declarations
// Mat img = imread("white.jpg");
// Mat src = imread("Rainbro.png");
Mat src = imread("multi.jpg");
// Mat src = imread("DarkRed.png");
Mat Hist;
Mat HSV;
Mat Edges;
Mat Grey;

vector<vector<Vec3b>> hueMEAN;
vector<vector<Point>> contours;

// Variables
int edgeThreshold = 1;
int const max_lowThreshold = 100;
int ratio = 3;
int kernel_size = 3;
int lowThreshold = 0;

// Windows
namedWindow("img", WINDOW_NORMAL);
namedWindow("HSV", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("Edges", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("contours", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

// Color Transforms
cvtColor(src, HSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
cvtColor(src, Grey, CV_BGR2GRAY);
// Perform Hist Equalization to help equalize Red hues so they stand out for 
// better Edge Detection

equalizeHist(Grey, Grey);


// Image Transforms
blur(Grey, Edges, Size(3, 3));
Canny(Edges, Edges, max_lowThreshold, lowThreshold * ratio, kernel_size);
findContours(Edges, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

//Rainbro MAT
//Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(432, 700, CV_8UC1);

//Multi MAT
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(630, 1200, CV_8UC1);

//Red variation Mat
//Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(600, 900, CV_8UC1);

vector <vector<Point>> ContourPoints;

/* This code for loops through all contours and assigns the value of the y coordinate as a parameter
for the row pointer in the HSV mat. The value vec3b pointer pointing to the pixel in the mat is accessed
and stored for any Hue value that is between 0-10 and 165-179 as Red only contours.*/

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    vector<Vec3b> vf;
    vector<Point> points;
    bool isContourRed = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++) {
        //Row Y-Coordinate of Mat from Y-Coordinate of Contour
        int MatRow = int(contours[i][j].y);
        //Row X-Coordinate of Mat from X-Coordinate of Contour
        int MatCol = int(contours[i][j].x);

        Vec3b *HsvRow = HSV.ptr <Vec3b>(MatRow);

        int h = int(HsvRow[int(MatCol)][0]);
        int s = int(HsvRow[int(MatCol)][1]);
        int v = int(HsvRow[int(MatCol)][2]);

        cout << "Coordinate: ";
        cout << contours[i][j].x;
        cout << ",";
        cout << contours[i][j].y << endl;
        cout << "Hue: " << h << endl;

        // Get contours that are only in the red spectrum Hue 0-10, 165-179
        if ((h <= 10 || h >= 165 && h <= 180) && ((s > 0) && (v > 0))) {
            cout << "Coordinate: ";
            cout << contours[i][j].x;
            cout << ",";
            cout << contours[i][j].y << endl;
            cout << "Hue: " << h << endl;

            vf.push_back(Vec3b(h, s, v));
            points.push_back(contours[i][j]);
            isContourRed = true;
        }

    }
    if (isContourRed == true) {
        hueMEAN.push_back(vf);
        ContourPoints.push_back(points);
    }
}

drawContours(drawing, ContourPoints, -1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2, 8);

// Calculate Mean and STD for each Contour
cout << "contour Means & STD of Vec3b:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < hueMEAN.size(); i++) {

    Scalar meanTemp = mean(hueMEAN.at(i));
    Scalar sdTemp;
    cout << i << ": " << endl;
    cout << meanTemp << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    meanStdDev(hueMEAN.at(i), meanTemp, sdTemp);
    cout << sdTemp << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
}
cout << "Actual Contours: " << contours.size() << endl;
cout << "# Contours: " << hueMEAN.size() << endl;

imshow("img", src);
imshow("HSV", HSV);
imshow("Edges", Edges);
imshow("contours", drawing);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```